# How to implement a containsAll method

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to implement a `containsAll` method, but I don't understand why it's returning incorrect results. Please, help me.

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    for (int ob = 0; ob < size; ob++) {
        if (o == obj[ob])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}



public boolean containsAll(MyList c) {
    for (int ob = 0; ob < size; ob++) {
        c.toArray();
        if (c.contains(obj[ob]))

        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It returns an incorrect result, because you return `true` after the first matching element is found. The logic should be along the lines of:

```
for (int ob = 0; ob < size; ob++) {
    /* ... */
    if (!c.contains(obj[ob])) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

I.e. return `false` after finding the first non-matching element, and only return `true` after checking all elements.

Also note that using `==`, you're performing a strict identity comparison. If that's not what you're after, consider using `equals()` instead.

Comment: Note that as a consquence of this implementation, every collection contains the empty collection. This is a vacuous truth (if you treat a collection as a Set).